# Nav bar is vertical and i need it horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstraps 3 to create a nav bar and for the life of me I cannot get it to layout the way I would like. I am having a hard time learning all these bootstrap classes. Anyways I would like all 5 of my elements here to be layed out horizontally in a single row but as you will see in the fiddle all 5 components are on a different row. Any suggestions?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cdewey/7M7sj/1/

Code:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="form form-horizontal" role="form">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class='input-group date row' id='datetimepicker1' data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD">
                                <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class='input-group date row' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class='input-group date row' id='datetimepicker3'>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                pickDate: false
            });
            $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                pickDate: false
            });
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                pickTime: false
            });
        });
    </script>
</nav>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Comment: i've been using those examples with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Use this tag to open the menu div:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

Look this really clear example to understand how it works: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: the problem with that very clear example is that none of the elements are form elements and are all inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FjnQL/)

You must remove the `<div class="form-group">` after the `li` and put it just after the `ul`.
The `<div class="form-group">` just creates separate entities for every `li`. Look at the demo I provided. You will understand.